# How to by pass interactive rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, spree

In Spree 3.1 after bundle install. It need to run rake as follow the document:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rake db:seed
bundle exec rake spree_sample:load
```

So I have a project to create a  rake task for Heroku post deployment. But problem is the db:seed asked default [username] and [password] which required [Enter] [Enter].

Really don't know how to make it go through 
And when I put in one task would look like this

```
task :autoall do
  Rake::Task["db:migrate"].invoke
  Rake::Task["db:seed"].invoke # This step stucked waiting for Enter
  Rake::Task["spree_sample:load"].invoke
end
```

The one below better but still waiting for [Enter] [Enter] in the process and die.

```
task :autoall do
    Rake::Task["db:reset"].invoke
    Rake::Task["spree_sample:load"].invoke
end
```

If no other way, I might need to dig in the source and modify. 
Help Please!

Comment: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/tasks/core.rake take a look in here, seems there are some environment variables to skip the prompts.

Comment: @zetetic Great, I just added AUTO_ACCEPT=1 Then it ran through the end. Done Thk.